# LINQ Query with subqueries VS Query and foreach

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have a very large amount of data that I need to gather for a report I am generating. All of this data comes from a Database that I am connected to via entity framework. For this query I have tried doing this a few different ways but no matter what I do it seems to be slow.

Overall I am curious if it is more efficient to have a LINQ query that has sub queries or is it better to do a foreach and then query for those values.

additional information for the DB a lot of the sub queries/loop iterations would be querying most of the largest tables in the DB.

Example code:

```
var b = (from brk in entities.Brokers
         join pcy in Policies on brk.BrkId equals pcy.pcyBrkId
         where pcy.DateStamp > twoYearsAgo
         select new returnData
         {
         BroId = brk.brkId,
         currentPrem = (from pcy in Policies
                        where pcy.PcyBrkID = brk.Brk.Id && pcy.InvDate > startDate && pcy.InvDate < endDate
                        select pcy.Premium).Sum(),
         //  5 more similar subqueries
         }).GroupBy(x=> x.BrkId).Select(x=> x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

OR

```
var b = (from brk in entities.Brokers
             join pcy in Policies on brk.BrkId equals pcy.pcyBrkId
             where pcy.DateStamp > twoYearsAgo
             select new returnData
             {
             BroId = brk.brkId
             }).GroupBy(x=> x.BrkId).Select(x=> x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
foreach( brk in b){
    // grab data from subqueries here
}
```

One additional detail may be that I may be able to filter out some additional information if I grab the primary information reducing the results to go through in the foreach.

Comment: If by doing a for each and querying you mean that you are querying each row in the database individually then that is going to be about the slowest method possible. Loops in SQL are also very slow, often exponentially worse than a set-based equivalent. Providing your table structure and queries is the only way you will get a true answer here though.

Comment: From what I've read...LINQ compiles down to the underlying foreach loops anyway so it is not faster. It can be more readable in my opinion but is harder to debug. As a general rule. Perform as much data manipulation in the database as possible.

Comment: Can you please post an example of both scenarios so I can provide a more accurate answer?

Comment: I guess one LINQ query should be more efficient as compared to doing multiple queries by looping against different values. If you could share the code, it will give better idea about your situation.

Comment: I'll add an edit for an example of the code structure for this.

Comment: This could cause DBA a headache in query plan optimization so I suggest you use stored proc instead.

Comment: What database are you using.  SQL Server has command line executable that are designed for archiving the database are running 10x faster than inside VS.  I usually run as a Process Class and put output into a CSV file.  Then read CSV into c#.  I use SQLCMD.exe : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine

Answer (score 2):

First of all, matters of performance always warrant profiling, no matter how reasonable or logical one or another solution might seem.

Saying that, usually, while working with database, less trips you do to database is better. Hence in your case it *might* be more efficient to have one single `SQL` query that retrieves big chunk of data over network, and after you process it locally with loops and whatnot. This guideline has to be an optimal solution for most cases.

All, obviously, depends on how big that data is, how big your network bandwidth is, and how fast and tuned your database is.

Side note: in general, if you work with big, or complex (intertwined) data, better to avoid using `Entity Framework` at all, especially when you're concerned about performance. Not sure if that might work for you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!
I wish I wasn't Tied to EF for this project... It has caused quite a few head aches for development. However, my hands are tied on this one :/

Comment: `EF` is an excellent product, don't make mistake. It just might not be a best solution when things become a little bit more complex. But it definitely has its own place, and does its job properly. You definitely can go along with it, just you need to profile your queries, and see what is happening under the hood,

Comment: I can't think of a scenario where querying the database N number of times for each data row would be faster than querying a single time for one dataset. But I understand that you don't want to make the recommendation without knowing the environment.